# Is universal newlines mode supposed to be default behaviour for open() in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running Python 2.7.2 (64 Bit) on Windows 7. I'm a little confused about 'universal newline mode' documented here: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open

From the documentation it seems 'universal newline mode' should not be in effect unless a 'U' is specified in the mode parameter of open(). However I see that as the default behavior! So is the documentation indeed misleading or am I missing something?

```
f = open("c:/Temp/test.txt", "wb")
f.write("One\r\nTwo\r\nThree\r\nFour"); f.close()

f = open("c:/Temp/test.txt", "rb")
f.read(); f.close()
'One\r\nTwo\r\nThree\r\nFour'

f = open("c:/Temp/test.txt", "r")
f.read(); f.close()
'One\nTwo\nThree\nFour'

f = open("c:/Temp/test.txt", "rt")
f.read(); f.close()
'One\nTwo\nThree\nFour'

f = open("c:/Temp/test.txt", "rU")
f.read(); f.close()
'One\nTwo\nThree\nFour'
```

Seems like "r", "rt", "rU" all have the same behavior?

Comment: on a related note, the documentation says, 'Python is usually built with _universal newlines support_'. Is there a programmatic way to find out if it **was not** built with _universal newlines support_ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're observing this because `\r\n` is the line terminator on Windows, so the `t` mode converts it to `\n`. On Unix (MacOS here), `t` doesn't affect `\r\n` and there's no conversion. The difference between `t` and `U` is that `U` converts `\r\n` and `\r` to `\n` on every platform, while `t` is platform dependent and only converts LT for the given platform.

Replace your test string to `"One\r\nTwo\nThree\rFour"` to see the effect of `U`.

Comment: thanks! on a related note, the documentation says, 'Python is usually built with _universal newlines support_'. Is there a programmatic way to find out if it **was not** built with _universal newlines support_ ?

Comment: @PuneetArora: yes, see `newlines` attribute in http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) documentation explains it.

Basically when you open as a text file (without `'b'`), *the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written*. Use binary mode if you don't want this.