# Replace '\n' in a string in Python 2.7

Tags: string, replace, newline, python-2.x

This is my file.txt:

```
Egg and Bacon;
Egg, sausage and Bacon
Egg and Spam;
Spam Egg Sausage and Spam;
Egg, Bacon and Spam;
```

I wanna convert the newLine '\n' to ' $ '. I just used:

```
f = open(fileName)
text = f.read()      
text = text.replace('\n',' $ ')
print(text)
```

This is my output:

```
$ Spam Egg Sausage and Spam;
```

and my output must be like:

```
Egg and Bacon; $ Egg, sausage and Bacon $ Egg ...
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using `#-*- encoding: utf-8 -*-`

Thank you.

Comment: Cannot reproduce; working as expected for me.

Comment: Does your text contain '\r' characters? What does print repr(text) print? I had no problems running your code; it works for me as intended.

Comment: print(repr(text)) = 'Egg and Bacon;\r\nEgg, sausage and Bacon\r\nEgg and Spam;\r\nSpam Egg Sausage and Spam;\r\n'

I made this change "replace('\r\n', ' $ ')" and now it works fine!
Thank you!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is universal newlines mode supposed to be default behaviour for open() in Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193047/is-universal-newlines-mode-supposed-to-be-default-behaviour-for-open-in-python)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible that your newlines are represented as `\r\n`. In order to replace them you should do:

```
text.replace('\r\n', ' $ ')
```

---

For a portable solution that works on both UNIX-like systems (which uses `\n`) and Windows (which uses `\r\n`), you can substitute the text using a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('\r?\n', ' $ ', 'a\r\nb\r\nc')
'a $ b $ c'
>>> re.sub('\r?\n', ' $ ', 'a\nb\nc')
'a $ b $ c'
```

Comment: An additional comment: I would recommend doing first `text = text.replace('\r\n','\n')` and then doing `text = text.replace('\n', ' $ ')`. This works for all files, for the ones having `'\n'` line separators and for the ones having `'\r\n'` line separators.

Comment: Yes, I agree that your regex solution is better. Got already my upvote, though.

Answer (score 6):

You can use splitlines.

```
lines = """Egg and Bacon;
Egg, sausage and Bacon
Egg and Spam;
Spam Egg Sausage and Spam;
Egg, Bacon and Spam;"""

print(" $ ".join(lines.splitlines()))
Egg and Bacon; $ Egg, sausage and Bacon $ Egg and Spam; $ Spam Egg Sausage and Spam; $ Egg, Bacon and Spam;
```

Or simply use rstrip and join on the file object without reading all into memory:

```
with open("in.txt") as f: 
    print(" $ ".join(line.rstrip() for line in f))
    Egg and Bacon; $ Egg, sausage and Bacon $ Egg and Spam; $ Spam Egg Sausage and Spam; $ Egg, Bacon and Spam;
```

Which is a much more efficient solution than reading all the file into memory and  using a regex. You should also always use `with` to open your files as it closes them automatically.

rstrip will remove `\n` `\r\n` etc..

```
In [41]: s = "foo\r\n"
In [42]: s.rstrip()
Out[42]: 'foo'    
In [43]: s = "foo\n"    
In [44]: s.rstrip()
Out[44]: 'foo'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
text = text.replace('\\n', '')
```

Comment: This is wrong; the input does not actually contain backslashes.